# Syntax error with killprocess class

Tags: c#, process

I have the following code in my system.

```
 private void killprocess()
    {
        Process[] procs = null;
        try
        {
            procs = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad");
            Process NotepadProc = procs[0];
            if (!NotepadProc.HasExited)
            {
                NotepadProc.Kill();
            }
            else if (procs != null)
                foreach (Process p in procs)
                {
                    p.Dispose();
                }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

The program gets notepad from the list of process and ends it.
My problem is that if notepad is not running I get this error.
[image]

I know what it is telling however I cant seem to get the code right to first check run an if statement that checks if notepad is running and if it is not running not not close is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IndexOutOfRangeException will occour at this step:
Process NotepadProc = procs[0];

You could check the length of your list.

Example:

```
if(procs.Length == 0)
   return;
```

or

```
if(procs.Length > 0)
{
   your code
}
```